# Display correct currency dependent on browser culture

Tags: asp.net, globalization, culture

My website will target UK and US markets, and i need to display a different price/currency for both markets - what is the best way around this?

1) a simple drop down box asking users preference?
2) Using culture class in asp .net to auto detect eg System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture

...or is there another better way?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim clientLocale as string = Request.UserLanguages(0).ToString.ToLower
```

This will either be "en_gb" or "en_us" or something else, in which case ask them.

This guys site talks about this issue. http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/334.aspx

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

When a request is made, it has an associated set of languages that are set by the user's browser. This set can be accessed using the [UserLanguages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.userlanguages.aspx) property of `HttpRequest`.

If you check this set, it will contain the user's language preferences (the same list that is in Tools -> Internet Options -> Languages in IE). You can use this to see the user's preferred culture and *automatically* switch currency based on that.

This list is dependent upon the "Standards and Formats" setting in Regional Setting in Control Panel.

My regional settings are set to use UK formats, so my languages list is `en-gb`. This list can contain more that one value, in which case it shows the user's preferred order.